# Django import-export how to replace integer ids with uuid ids?

Tags: json, django, uuid, django-import-export

I am building a django application where the user can export a json file of many models which are related to each other. Then the json fiele can be imported on another server. Since its an other database i can not use the ids which are exported in the file.

I use django import-export for that. How can i replace the integer ids from my database with uuids to prevent double id problems? (especially when using foreign keys or many to many relations). In the following code does not work completely since Group.name is not unique.

I would like to create a separate id system for import export without an influence on the id's on the database, since i think id handling should be left to the database otherwise you will get trouble.

model.py

```
class Group(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Subgroup(models.Model):
    parent_group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

resources.py

```
parent_group_widget = fields.Field(
column_name='group_natural_key',
attribute='parent_group',
widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Group, 'name'))

class GroupResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        exclude = ('id',)
        import_id_fields = ('name', 'measurement_widget')


class SubgroupResource(resources.ModelResource):
    parent_group_widget = parent_group_widget
    class Meta:
        model = Subgroup
        exclude = ('id',)
        import_id_fields = ('name', 'parent_group_widget')
```

I would like to get the following result:

```
{"Group": [
    {
        "id": "1c4d4824-d890-4021-bb24-18dd5a2cd618", 
        "name": "Group_0", 
    }]
"Subgroup": [
    {
        "name": "FOOBAR", 
        "parent_group": "1c4d4824-d890-4021-bb24-18dd5a2cd618", 
    }
}
```

Comment: So the problem is that in new database the Ids are already occupied?
If yes then in old database increment the ids by some number lets say +9999 in both tables and then import.

Comment: @User42 yea that would kind of work, but fiddling with ids in the database is good plan to create a bag of pain later on.

Comment: True. You can create a copy to fiddle with.